# How to get friends id,name,profile picture from facebook?

Tags: facebook, graph

I am creating an application. I want to access the friend list with their id,name,profile picture. But i am access only friend name,picture with the help of following url
    http://graph.facebook.com/me/taggable_friend?access_token=.......

Above url display name,id,profile picture but the id is not valid. I want to access the valid id.

So, please any one help me.

Comment: You get friends by using /me/friends

Comment: But /me/friends will only return friends that uses the app. And you can't get the id of friends that are not using the app. But if you tell what you need the id for it would be easier to help you

Comment: I need the id to by which i can get the friends of his/her friends

Comment: Doesn't matter if you get the id. You will still not be able to get their friends

Comment: To be able to fetch someones friends they first have to login to your app and then grant the permission `user_friends`. If they don't do both of those things you will not be able to fetch their friends

Comment: anyone found a way to do this?